# How to express the set of solutions of an equation in terms of $\mathbb R, \mathbb Z, \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $\mathbb R$ the set of real numbers, $\mathbb Z$ the set of integers, $\mathbb N$ the set of natural numbers.

If $S$ be the solution set of the equation $(x)^2+[x]^2=(x-1)^2+[x+1]^2$ where $(x)$ is the least integer greater than or equal to $x$ and $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$, then

A: $S = \mathbb R$

B: $S = \mathbb R - \mathbb Z$

C: $S = \mathbb R - \mathbb N$

what i've done this far:

$\{(x-1) \}^2 = \{ (x)-1 \}^2=(x)^2-2(x)+1$ and similarly for $[x+1]$; therefore the equation becomes $[x]-(x)+1=0$

if $x= n$ ($n$ belongs to $\mathbb Z$), then $n-n+1=0$ (which is not possible)

if $x=n+k$, such that $0<k<1$, then n-{n+k}+1=0 is true for all values of $n$ and $k$

NOW MY QUESTION: 
How do i proceed from here to get the answer in terms of the option given?

Comment: also if someone can suggest edits for the title it'll be great! :)

Comment: Notice that -1 does not satisfy the equation.

Comment: @Jeroen which one? and -1 as the value of what term?

Comment: $x=-1$ doesn't satisfy $(x)^2+[x]^2 = (x-1)^2+[x+1]^2$. So $-1 \notin S$. Thus A and C can't be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(x)^2+[x]^2-(x-1)^2-[x+1]^2$. For $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(k)=k$ and $[k]=k$, so $f(k)=-2\not=0$. Thus $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ is not in the solution set, eliminating A and C. So pick B.

Comment: the correct option in B.
k lies between 0 and 1, so how does f(k)=-2 fit?

Comment: Sorry, the reasoning leads to B, I just typed A.

Comment: i didn't understand the reasoning :/
k doesn't have to belong to Z.

Comment: It shows that if $x\in\mathbb Z$, it can't be a solution. This eliminates A and C.

Comment: but the k=-2 part. that's what i didn't get.

Comment: Evaluate the function at an arbitrary integer $k$. You will get $-2$, which isn't zero, and thus there are no integer zeros of $f$. Hence, there are no integer solutions to the original equation.

Comment: okay.. that makes sense!